# user permissions for programs

Tags: 16.04, user-management

I am running 16.04 and my administrator account has programs I consider distracting when it comes to doing work.

I know how to add a second user account, but I want to know how to make it so I can still access Skype/Chrome/LibreOffice from a new user account but not Steam and similar apps.

Comment: You want to make then *inaccesoble* or *invisible*?

Answer (score -1):

You should see the command [`chmod`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) and [`id`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id).

Comment: Please put in some examples to help OP.

Comment: For example `chmod 0777 ./` will allow everyone access the folder